# How to solve netbeans cannot find symbol for ZonedDateTime toInstant() method

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am trying to get milliseconds representation of time from a LocalDateTime object, as follow.

[image]

The problem is as you can see in the attached image, Netbeans cannot find the toInstant() method and the code can not be compiled.

I have searched the internet for solutions but ones i have found, have failed to solve my issue. Many suggests to set my project's sources to jdk 8 and yes its 8. I also tried deleting Netbeans caches, performed a clean and build but nothing seems to help.

Has anyone solved this issue before? if yes please your help will be life saving.

Comment: cross check your imports

Comment: RC I have all the imports in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Netbeans 8.2 solved this problem. It happens that Netbeans 7 could not handle some new java 1.8 functionalities most especially the default methods for interfaces.